# Error running pyttsx3 code on OS X: "NameError: name 'objc' is not defined"

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc, pyttsx3

I am trying to run this program using Python 3.11.5 on macOS Ventura 13.6:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.say("Hello, how are you today?")

engine.runAndWait()
```

But I am getting this error and I don't know where to start looking:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raelynmarie/Desktop/Tester.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 12, in <module>
    class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 13, in NSSpeechDriver
    @objc.python_method
     ^^^^
NameError: name 'objc' is not defined. Did you mean: 'object'?
```

I reinstalled the dependencies following a different order and that did not fix the error.

Order of installation:

- pyobjc-core
- pyobjc-framework-Cocoa
- pyobjc-framework-Quartz
- pyobjc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked pypi and I found `py3-tts`:
https://pypi.org/project/py3-tts/

I followed the installation for py3-tts and it works now without the dummy parameter!

Answer (score 3):

I did not have success with the setup you had. Originally I ran:

`pip install pyttsx3` and got an error that objc was not defined, the same error you're referring to. I ran `pip install objc` and had no success either.

Running `pip install py3-tts` worked. Recommend trying this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use call `init` like this.

```
engine = pyttsx3.init("nsss")
```

You can check [engine factory](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#the-engine-factory) from the pyttsx3 documentation: https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'dummy' parameter

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('dummy')
```

Comment: **Update**
I checked pypi and followed the install for py3-tts and it works now without the dummy parameter! Hopefully this works for you too!

https://pypi.org/project/py3-tts/